# How to access way coordinates from a large (.json-based) list structure

Tags: python, json, geojson

For each individual way, I am trying to build a list of coordinates from all the "nodes" associated with that particular "way".

I thought, since everything was in this large list (aka "elements":) I could just use a 'for' loop...but it turns out...I cannot access the "type" : "node" (i.e. where the coordinates are) this way.

How do I get to the matching coordinates in "type": "node" if I can't use a for loop??

Ex of list structure (you can see the full set for these two 'ways' [here](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%3Bway%28around%3A50%2C55%2E693309807744484%2C21%2E151986122131348%29%5B%22highway%22~%22secondary%22%5D%3Bout%20meta%20center%3B%3E%3Bout%20skel%20qt%3B%0A)...I just shortened it below):

```
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 57935838
  },
  "nodes": [
    279385160,
    1142007444
  ],
  "tags": {
    "highway": "secondary",
    "name": "Kauno g."
  }
},
{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 223130469
  },
  "nodes": [
    470874618,
    2362142222
  ],
  "tags": {
    "highway": "secondary",
    "name": "Agluonos g."
  }
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 470874618,
  "lat": 55.6933076,
  "lon": 21.1517616
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 2362142222,
  "lat": 55.6931543,
  "lon": 21.1514953
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 1142007444,
  "lat": 55.6991153,
  "lon": 21.1647621
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 279385160,
  "lat": 55.7001553,
  "lon": 21.1671538
}
]
```

What I get if I use the 'for' loop on elements (for id = 57935838}:

```
{u'tags': {u'name': u'Kauno g.', u'highway': u'secondary'}, u'nodes': [279385160, 1142007444], u'type': u'way', u'id': 57935838}
```

ex:

```
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen

    all_data_dict = get_overpass_json_data(line_url2)

    with open(outfile, 'w') as geojson_file:
        for item in all_data_dict['elements']:
            print item
```

ex (of a two noded way from [here](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%3Bway%28150672234%29%3Bout%20meta%20center%3B%3E%3Bout%20skel%20qt%3B%0A)):

```
>> print all_data_dict

>> {u'elements': [{u'changeset': 29434078, u'uid': 91490, u'tags': {u'bridge': u'yes', u'layer': u'1', u'ref': u'F72', u'surface': u'asphalt', u'highway': u'tertiary'}, u'timestamp': u'2015-03-12T19:56:59Z', u'version': 2, u'user': u'Heinz_V', u'nodes': [1635609339, 1635609329], u'type': u'way', u'id': 150672234, u'center': {u'lat': 27.5894941, u'lon': 85.4801512}}, {u'lat': 27.5894735, u'lon': 85.4800892, u'type': u'node', u'id': 1635609329}, {u'lat': 27.5895146, u'lon': 85.4802131, u'type': u'node', u'id': 1635609339}], u'version': 0.6, u'osm3s': {u'timestamp_osm_base': u'2015-05-10T18:01:02Z', u'copyright': u'The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.'}, u'generator': u'Overpass API'}
```

Comment: What do you mean `I cannot access the "type" : "node" (i.e. where the coordinates are) this way.`? I don't know what your `for` loop looks like, but if you get a dict named `value` that looks like the one you say you got, `value['nodes']` is the list `[279385160, 1142007444]`, which is exactly what you seem to want.

Comment: Presumably there's something wrong in your code that makes this not work, but without seeing any of that code, and only seeing a description that seems to imply that the code is working rather than telling us what's wrong, I have no idea what your bug could be. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help.

Comment: {
  "type": "node",
  "id": 2362142222,
  "lat": 55.6931543,
  "lon": 21.1514953
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 1142007444,
  "lat": 55.6991153,
  "lon": 21.1647621
}, I am not trying to get to the id (values) of the 'nodes' but the coords. Why are they not part of the items in the 'elements' list?

Comment: What you've shown us isn't valid JSON (or a valid Python dict). For example, the first dict in elements is `{ "type": "way", "id": 57935838 }`, and then the next thing is `nodes: …`, which isn't a valid list member. Please give us a real stripped-down example of your data that we can parse either mentally or in code.

Comment: @abarnert How is it not valid json? I've added a full print of the 'all_data_dict' (which is the full json) of a two node way (bottom of the orig. post). If you click the link you can see where I sourced it from...

Comment: If you just run `json.loads` on it, Python will tell you how it's not valid JSON. But look at the structure: The first element of the `elements` array is an object that starts with the `{` on line 3, and ends with the `}` on line 6. The next thing after that is `"nodes": […]`. You can't have a key-value pair in an array, so something is already broken. If you ignore that, and the next error of the same kind with `"tags": […]`, then you have a `}` with no matching `{`.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not going to fetch your original data and figure out how to strip out a small sample for you. Read the MCVE link. You need to do that. Or, if you don't want to, the best answers you're going to get are guesses (if you're lucky—I see that two other people just downvoted the question without comment and gave up) which may or may not actually be relevant to your actual problem because we may have guessed wrong. (And if you don't even comment on the answer, I can't improve that guess.)

Comment: Meanwhile, you still haven't shown us the code that supposedly uses a `for` loop on the elements to find `id = 57935838`, and I have no idea what that code would look like, and I don't know what you wanted it to do instead of what it did, so I can't tell you how to fix it. I showed you what you _can_ do with a guess at what your data might be, and hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to figure out what you're trying to do or what your problem is from an invalid JSON fragment, a vague description, and no code, but…

I think your `elements` is supposed to be a list with a bunch of dicts in it, each of which has a `type`. You want all of the elements whose `type` is the string `'node'`. And then, for each of them, you want the `lat` and `lon` values. So, let's write that:

```
coords = []
for element in elements:
    if element['type'] == 'node':
        coords.append((element['lat'], element['lon']))
```

Or, more briefly:

```
[(e['lat'], e['lon']) for e in elements if e['type'] == 'node']
```

That won't run on your broken example, but if I remove the two stray `}` before each of the `nodes` keys in the first two elements so it'll parse (of course I'm just guessing at whether that's what your actual structure is supposed to be…), I get this:

```
[(55.6933076, 21.1517616),
 (55.6931543, 21.1514953),
 (55.6991153, 21.1647621),
 (55.7001553, 21.1671538)]
```

---

If you'd rather have that as, say, a dict mapping each node's ID to its lat/lon tuple, same idea:

```
coords = {}
for element in elements:
    if element['type'] == 'node':
        coords[element['id']] = (element['lat'], element['lon'])
```

Or:

```
{e['id']: (e['lat'], e['lon']) for e in elements if e['type'] == 'node'}
```

Which gives me:

```
{279385160: (55.7001553, 21.1671538),
 470874618: (55.6933076, 21.1517616),
 1142007444: (55.6991153, 21.1647621),
 2362142222: (55.6931543, 21.1514953)}
```